# No matching activity error in React Native/Expo on Android

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

I have a React Native/Expo app, and since migrating to Android SDK 30, I have been receiving several "no matching activity errors", and then "browser has already been launched" errors when on Android.

This has only been a problem with SDK 30 - SDK 29 had no such issues. But now that SDK 30 is obligatory for the Google Play store, it's important to figure out what this problem is, so that I can get out further versions of an Android app.

https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/12045

This link describes several other people dealing with the problem and attempted solutions.

My guess is that it has something to do with `<query>` tags, but I haven't done a ton of native Android development myself, so I'm not completely certain.

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example from GitHub?

Comment: @MuhammadNuman There's literally a reproducible demo right in the first post on the link? try {
  await WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync("https://www.google.co.uk");
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e.message); // === "No matching activity"
}

Comment: Just put that into a blank project and export to bare workflow

Comment: it is not reproducing on my side